# Webpack entry point syntax confusion

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was studying some code to understand `webpack` and what it does and came across this code;

```
const path = require('path');
const docsBuild = {
  entry: {
    'app/docs/lib/dice-roller': './app/src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(_dirname,''),
    filename: '[name].js'
  } 
};
module.exports = [docsBuild];
```

I can't understand why in place of the property of entry main, there is a file path and why the second parameter of `path.join` is empty. I'm new to `webpack` and I couldn't seem to find my answer in its documentation, maybe I didn't search well but help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the webpack documentation:

[entry](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context#entry):

> The point or points to enter the application. At this point the
>   application starts executing. If an array is passed all items will be
>   executed.

So the piece of code:

```
entry: {
  'app/docs/lib/dice-roller': './app/src/main.js'
}
```

Is setting the entry point for `'app/docs/lib/dice-roller'` to `'./app/src/main.js'`

[output.path](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath):

> The output directory as an absolute path.

The second parameter of `path.join` is the output directory name itself. In your example is empty but, as you can see in the [example provided here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#using-a-configuration), for the below project structure:

```
  webpack-demo
  |- package.json
  |- webpack.config.js
  |- /dist
  |- /src
```

You may set this output configuration where [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) returns the the directory name of the current module:

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
```

Also [this 'options' documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options) has a paragraph which may clarify this a little bit:

> Notice that throughout the configuration we use Node's built-in [path
>   module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and prefix it with the [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) global. This prevents file
>   path issues between operating systems and allows relative paths to
>   work as expected. See [this section](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix) for more info on POSIX vs. Windows
>   paths.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @juanlumn . Though, does the path.join statement as written mean that the output directory will be the current directory? And in the entry statement, does the first file path need to be in existence because when i looked through the rest of the project i couldn't find the libs folder at all.

Comment: @Linda 'the output directory will be the current directory?' I think so, yes. does the first file path need to be in existence? Is not a file path itself, is a string naming an entrypoint like in a map, key: value.